# I have display data into php and my sql but it is not display properly

Tags: php, mysql

My code is given below

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'sanjay');
?>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $rows = array();
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM registration';
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
        $rows = $result->fetch_assoc();
        print_r($rows);
        die;

        ?>
        <div>
            <table>
                <h1>User Table</h1>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Password</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $rows['password']; ?></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

my actual problem is it is display only 1 record in table, when i am debug this code using this   print_r($rows);
        die;
it also display only 1 record like this

```
 Array ( [id] => 4 [name] => Anand Dayal [email] => kanand81@gmail.com [password] => admin )
```

where am i wrong please suggest me

Comment: Please go read up on what the methods you are using actually do! https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Did you read the manual? `$result->fetch_assoc();` returns just one row, so you need a loop to get the rest.

Comment: i am using while loop but its given error like this  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_fetch_array()

Comment: `while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())` will do the magic, Luke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments suggest, you need to loop as `$result->fetch_assoc();`

**Solution:**

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['id'];
}
```

[Further reading](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: How could I have known :)